# Javascript - Dynamically loading JS file from JS issues

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues loading a JS file within JS. I was hoping to get some help.

so basically we have something like this. I dumbed it down as we do not need all the code for everything in here as its quite complex.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainJSCode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var grabCode = [];
if(something==true) {

    function loadScript(url, callback)
    {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        script.onreadystatechange = callback;
        script.onload = callback;
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    loadScript("js/my.js", runJS);
    function runJS(){
        for(var i = 0;i < 100; i++) {
        grabCode.push(someFunctionInsideHereReturnsStuff());
        }
    alert(grabCode.length); //=100
    };
    alert(grabCode.length); //=0 for some reason
}
```

So this is basically it I stripped out a lot. I just need to get some stuff from my.js into this js file and use the code from there.

Why is the global var grabCode not being global? Sorry, I am a bit rusty and my scope is way off for some reason.

If there is a better way to load in the my.js so I can access its code directly I would be up for that help as well.

Comment: Can you post what is in the my.js file?

Comment: See [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Your *runJS* function is *invoked after* the last statement in your code, because it is only executed when the script has been loaded *asynchronously*.

Comment: Hey Matt, Its a whole bunch of stuff that really does not matter for what I am trying to do. It will just confuse. We can pretend its a function that returns the numbers 1-100.

Comment: @trincot would there be a better way of doing this then to get the code out of my.js to run in here?

Comment: see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asydg3ve/)

Comment: @Alessandro I cant use jquery though.

Comment: It's just an example, I'm inculding JQuery library dinamically and then I use it... you could include your js and use it in a function "onload".

Comment: Ok thanks @alessandro I will go that route